# Why is my data becoming zero in NSMutableArray in iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application I am adding the data in NSMutableArray with a for loop. All is added correctly but the issue is that if the number of iterations are increasing the data becomes zero at particular index values. My code looks as follows:

```
  NSArray * sortedArray =[FilterProjectsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
  NSMutableArray *Array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sortedArray];
 [appdelegate.filtersArray addObject:[Array1 mutableCopy]] ;

 for (int i=0; i<[appdelegate.filtersArray count]; i++)
 {
       NSLog(@"object in filtersarray count is %d",[[appdelegate.filtersArray objectAtIndex:i]count]);

 }
```

For this I am getting the output in the console as follows:

```
object in filtersarray count is 9

object in filtersarray count is 9
object in filtersarray count is 2


object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 2
object in filtersarray count is 9


object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 9
object in filtersarray count is 2


object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 2
object in filtersarray count is 3


object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 0
object in filtersarray count is 3
```

That's the output I'm getting, I don't have an idea why it behaves like this. So if anyone has any idea regarding this please let me know.

Comment: is your appdelegate.filtersArray mutable?

Answer (score 0):

simply do addObject:Array1 then

```
[Array 1 release];
```

if you are not using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to do mutable copy when you are adding the array as an object

```
[appdelegate.filtersArray addObject:Array1] ;
```

Comment: Hi Neo Thanks For your Reply. Actually i have to add Array1 (array) in another array that is appdelegate.filtersArray.

Comment: Was there other objects in the filtersArray or it was nil before u added array1?

Comment: Even after removing that MutableCopy Also i am getting same output. No actually i am getting the data from server and perform sorting on that data and storing in Array1 after sorting. Then After that i am adding that array1 to appdelegate.filtersArray . This actually i am doing .

Comment: if there were no objects inside the fltersarray before addin your array1 do [appdelegate.filtersArray removeAllObjects];

Comment: No i have to use this appdelegate.filtersarray in my application so i cannot clear this array.

Comment: i mean if you does not contain object that you need to use later, remove all objects and then add the array1

Comment: yes ur correct but i can not remove the objects in filtersarray because i have to use that later.

Comment: do this... just print your filtersArray and see what it contains.

Comment: After this what i am getting that only i mentioned in my question.

Comment: i mean do this NSLog(@"%@",appdelegate.filtersArray);

Comment: i am not saying that will solve the problem... just check what it contains.... may be you filtersarray contains numbers of array with some of them empty